# Send register name to mapped command

Tags: vim, vi, neovim

I made this command to send my current buffer's file path into the `+` register:

```
:nmap <Leader>yp :let @+=expand("%:p")<cr>
```

I'd like to extend it so that the user choose the register to send to when calling `<Leader>yp`, but I'm not sure how.

If there's a way to "capture the selected register", can I use it into my command to then allow something like `"a<Leader>yp`?
Thanks!

Comment: See `:help v:register`, `:help getreg()`, and `:help setreg()`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to romainl comment, I came to this solution:

```
:nmap <Leader>yp :call setreg(v:register, expand("%:p"))<cr>
```